# how to clone a unmerged git pull request given webhook information?(using script)

Tags: git

I've tried googling and haven't had much luck. The question is pretty straight forward. Given information from a github pullrequest webhook,how would one clone that pull request? Reason is because I plan to run some stuff on future pull request on a automated basis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/):

```
git fetch origin pull/<id>/head:<some_local_ref>
```